# QtSerialPort framing error

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port

I have built qtserialport for Qt4 and written a console application to log data from a device which sends information at 9600 bauds, 8 data bits, 1 stop bits and no parity, which I think is the default for serial communication. I have managed to open the port correctly and log the data as expected, but whenever I close the application or turn off the computer and try to restart the application it, the port opens but gives me a "framingError". If I close the application and then open the port using hyperterminal, the port opens correctly and then I am able to open my console application without errors. I have read that the framing error can be solved using parity, but I don't really know what settings to use or even that it is the solution to my problem.

```
    //constructor
    MyApp::MyApp()
    {
         QSerialPort *serialPort = new QSerialPort(this);

            connect(serialPort,
                    SIGNAL(error(QSerialPort::SerialPortError)),
                    this,SLOT(serialError(QSerialPort::SerialPortError)));

            serialPort->setPortName("COM1");
            serialPort->setBaudRate(9600,QSerialPort::Input);
            serialPort->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
            serialPort->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
            serialPort->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
            serialPort->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);

            if(serialPort->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
            {
                qDebug() << "Serial port opened at serialPort->portName();
            }
    }

    ...

    void myApp::serialError(QSerialPort::SerialPortError error)
    {
        if(error != QSerialPort::NoError)
        {
            QMetaEnum metaEnum =  QSerialPort::staticMetaObject.enumerator(
            QSerialPort::staticMetaObject.indexOfEnumerator("SerialPortError"));

            QString errStr(metaEnum.valueToKey(error));

            qDebug() << errStr;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pls post some code (initialisation part). In most of cases it's a result of improper baud rate setting. Then you run a hyper terminal it sets baudrate/parity/etc correctly so your application just reuse a proper setting thats why you don't have these errors.

Comment: @evliruff I have added the code, the settings are the same as in hyperterminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A framing error is generated when the UART doesn't detect the stop bit(s).  Common causes are:

- the wrong baud rate or changing the baud rate while the device is sending
- the device sends more data or parity bits than you expect
- a mismatch in the number of stop bits
- reconnecting the cable with the device powered up
- software not clearing the error state when the port is opened

If you get only a single framing error after opening the port then just ignore it.  If they fire constantly while the device is sending then you configured the port wrong.  Do avoid QSerialPort::NoFlowControl, most devices implement hardware handshaking.  A program like HyperTerminal will always turn it on.  Ask somebody that knows the device how it was configured so you can stop guessing.

Comment: thank you, though unfortunately it is not possible to as someone who knows the device. About flow control, I will try and changing the setting to QSerialPort::HardwareControl and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: By the way, I changed it and it didn't make a difference. I was trying to replicate the error, the only way it happened was when I forced the computer to shut down while the device was still sending data... again the only fix was to open hyperterminal and my app again.

Answer (score 0):

You incorrectly setup the serial port options. The serial port, at first, needs to be opened, and then configured! But not as at you currently do. In your code is a reason of all your problems with FramingError because your configuration aren't accepted (you at least check returned values at the set() methods). Because takes something previous configuration with enabled parity checking mode. Read documentation, look examples.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a statement to capture break interrupt of `Framing Error` event:

```
serialPort->notifyOnFramingError(true)
```

then,
in the catpure code segment, add 'break' statement to exit.